# How to pause/resume conversion of media file using ffmpeg in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I have successfully downloaded the media file from below command using ffmpeg in my application.
Now I want to pause during on progress of the download and again I resume the same after some time.

below ffmpeg command used for download and files saved successfully.

```
ffmpeg -i http://xx.xx-xxxxx-x.amazonaws.com/audio-output-stg/GaumeeLava51/01Track11513330525752/01Track11513330525752.m3u8 /sdcard/videokit/sample.mp3
```

Please help me with ffmpeg command and thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: No not yet. I moved to another lib called DOWNLOAD TO GO

Comment: can you help me on this?